# add jbutton at runtime

Tags: java, swing, sockets, client-server, jbutton

I am building an application on Socket programming in swing in which server listens for clients and if a client is connected I want

- A button should be added for each client if connected on server screen
- Add a listener on each button.For example add Send Message function for each client

I have created a thread in server which listens for client connections but I can not add jbutton at runtime.

Please reply.

Comment: What code you got so far?  Whats the Panel look like that you want populated?  You should take into account how many connections and how crowded the pane may get with each new client connection.

Comment: Of course the whole socket programming system is irrelevant to your problem. Make a little test program where when a user presses a ("static") button, new components (like more buttons) are dynamically added to the GUI. Try to do that and come back with specific problems. Not to mention that this question has been asked many many times: http://bit.ly/Oi7EUi

Comment: Hi, I have tested the program with two clients. The server is connected to two clients successfully. But buttons are not added at runtime for each client.

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you need ? :

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class NewButtonOnRunTime {
static JPanel panel;

static JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args){
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame = new JFrame("Add Buttons");

            JButton button = new JButton("Simulate new Client");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    JButton jb = new JButton("A new Client");
                    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is an button action");

                        }
                    });
                    panel.add(jb);
                    frame.revalidate();
                }
            });
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(button);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You do not call `invokeLater` in your main. Look at [Siwng's Hello World](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java)

Comment: @DSquare indeed your right but it's just a dummy exemple. And the executable here is self contained.

Comment: I don't know how "the executable is self contained" is relevant. Swing code must be executed in the EDT. Even the simplest -dummy- program, the HelloWorld has to do it, there is no way around it. Not doing it makes this a bad example, especially for newbies.

Comment: @DSquare there you go

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I have the class extending JFrame class and I have created a thread in main method for accepting client connections. And from the thread I am adding JButton but it is not getting added.

Comment: can you show us how you add the button? @sourabhgkr

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have some kind of isConnected bool,

```
if(isConnected){

JButton runTimeButton = new JButton();

runTimeButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        //do all the things you need to do in here,
        //alternatively, define this inner class somewhere else and pass in
        // an instance of it

        }
    });


frame.add(runTimeButton);


}
```

Comment: No, you must also call `frame.revalidate()`.

Comment: You should not use a MouseListener on buttons  users can active buttons with the key board as well. Updates to the UI should be made within the context of the EDT. Where possible, you should avoid adding content directly to the top level container

Answer (score 0):

Based on ServerSocket communication in java (i.e. TCP), if a client is connected to the server with a particular port say 5555, no other clients will not be able to connect to the server with the same port at the same time because the port is already in use. So, each client should be using different port if you want to get simultaneous communication with the clients.

Look at this sample code, it adds `JButton` at runtime when a new client is connected :
(run client code and server code in separate machine connected  together)

*Server code*

```
package com.test.socket;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ServerFrame extends JFrame {

    private Map<Integer, SocketVO> serverSocketMap;
    private int startingPort = 5555;

    public ServerFrame() {
    }

    public ServerFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        initComponents();
        serverSocketMap = new HashMap<Integer, SocketVO>();
        keepStartServerSocket();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTextArea area = null;

    private void initComponents() {

        area = new JTextArea(20, 20);
        add(area);
        // addDynamicButton();
    }

    private void addDynamicButton(final int port) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Client on " + port + " port");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                Socket socket = serverSocketMap.get(port).getSocket();
                try {
                    String content = area.getText();
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(content.getBytes());

                    System.out.println("seding text area content to " + port);
                    System.out.println(content);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    class SocketVO {
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private Socket socket;

        public ServerSocket getServerSocket() {
            return serverSocket;
        }

        public void setServerSocket(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
            this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
        }

        public Socket getSocket() {
            return socket;
        }

        public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

    }

    private void keepStartServerSocket() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("waiting for a client at port "
                            + startingPort);
                    openServerSocket(startingPort);
                    startingPort++;
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    private void openServerSocket(final int port) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            SocketVO socketVO = new SocketVO();
            socketVO.setServerSocket(serverSocket);
            socketVO.setSocket(socket);
            serverSocketMap.put(port, socketVO);
            addDynamicButton(port);

            checkForCosing(port, socket);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkForCosing(final int port, final Socket socket) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;
                try {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((read = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                        builder.append(new String(b));
                    }
                    if (builder.toString().equals("close")) {
                        closeServerSocket(port);
                        System.out.println("server port " + port + " closed");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * the method to close corresponding sockets
     * 
     * @param port
     */
    private void closeServerSocket(int port) {

        Socket socket = serverSocketMap.get(port).getSocket();
        ServerSocket serverSocket = serverSocketMap.get(port).getServerSocket();
        try {
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServerFrame("Server Socket Frame");
    }

}
```

*Client code :*

```
package com.test.socket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {
    private int startingPort = 5550;


    private void bindToServer() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", startingPort);
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;
                try {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    while((read = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                        builder.append(new String(b));
                    }
                    System.out.println("message from server : "+builder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                startingPort++;
            }

            if (startingPort == 5580) {

            }
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client().bindToServer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your last comment:

I have tested the program with two clients. The server is connected to two clients successfully. But buttons are not added at runtime for each client.

You are able to connect with multiple client and you have added a button also but it's not visible on the server.

> Calling `validate()` again on `JFrame` will solve your problem after adding new `JButton`.

Comment: Revalidate (or invalidate/validate. If it's not available) would be preferred as it won't make the window flicker

Comment: Thanks a lot. `validate()` works perfectly. I have updated in my post.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

private JButton field[];

public JButton[] getField() {
    return field;
}

public void test(int n) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    field = new JButton[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        field[i] = new JButton("" + i + "");
        field[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("clicked button");
            }
        });
        panel.add(field[i]);
    }
    add(panel);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setSize(300, 300);
    test.setVisible(true);
    test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    test.test(5);
}
```

}

Comment: There's nothing dynamic about this, OP wants to add buttons when a certain event happens, not in a constructor.